# Error while accessing associative array in PHP

Tags: php, html, associative-array

I have this code for my Calendar Booking System.

```
public class booking_diary
{
    public $bookings;

    function make_booking_array($year, $month)
    {
        $query = "SELECT * FROM bookings WHERE date LIKE '$year-$month%'";
        $result = mysqli_query($this->link, $query) or die(mysqli_error($this->link));

        $this->count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        $this->bookings = '';

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

            $this->bookings[] = array(
                "name" => $row['name'],
                "date" => $row['date'],
                "start" => $row['start'],
                "comments" => $row['comments'],
                "adminBooked" => $row['admin']
            );
        }

        $this->make_day_boxes($this->days, $this->bookings, $this->month, $this->year);

    } // Close function

    function make_day_boxes()
    {
        // I want to access $bookings['adminBooked'] in this function
    }

}
```

In function `make_day_boxes()` I tried to access `$bookings['adminBooked']`

But I get error that index *adminBooked* is undefined

Can anyone tell me how do I get access to value stored at 'adminBooked'?

//Why are most of here to down vote me. What is wrong if I am learning and asking my problems and questions here????

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to access a class variable in your class you need to access it with $this->

e.g.
$this->bookings['adminBooked'];

But you're also creating an indexed array when you do $this->bookings[] = array

so if you want to access any of the elements within it you'll have to go to the index you are interested in.

e.g.

```
function make_day_boxes($index){
return $this->bookings[$index]['adminBooked'];
}
```

Comment: But it says, index 'adminBooked' is undefined.

Comment: PHP doesn't force you to define variables, so if you have another method and just put $bookings['adminBooked'] then PHP will just create a new variable called $bookings at the local scope of that method. There will not be an index of adminBooked by default though, which is partial why you'd get that error. Plus the fact that you've added your array to an indexed array (which is the $this->bookings array)

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are creating multidimensional array.

Try accessing `$this->$bookings[0]['adminBooked'];`